# Rust float comparisons not working properly in Arduino Mega

Tags: rust, arduino, floating-point, embedded, comparison

I am trying to setup some Arduino based Rust code that uses F32's. If I perform addition or any style of cast to derive a float the comparisons end up being (wildly) wrong. If I have a fixed float number the comparisons work as expected.

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use panic_halt as _;
use ufmt_float::uFmt_f32;

#[arduino_hal::entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let dp = arduino_hal::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let pins = arduino_hal::pins!(dp);

    let mut serial = arduino_hal::default_serial!(dp, pins, 57600);
    
    loop {
        // let sample_rate = 280.0f32;
        let mut sample_rate = 100.0f32;
        for _ in 1..10 {
            sample_rate = sample_rate + 20.0f32;
        }
        
        let sample_rate_formatted = uFmt_f32::Five(sample_rate);

        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "Sample rate: {}", sample_rate_formatted).unwrap();

        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.to_bits() : {}",sample_rate.to_bits()).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.is_sign_negative() : {}",sample_rate.is_sign_negative()).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.is_sign_positive() : {}",sample_rate.is_sign_positive()).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.is_nan() : {}",sample_rate.is_nan()).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.is_finite() : {}",sample_rate.is_finite()).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.is_infinite() : {}",sample_rate.is_infinite()).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.is_normal() : {}",sample_rate.is_normal()).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.is_subnormal() : {}",sample_rate.is_subnormal()).unwrap();

        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.lt(0.0) : {}", sample_rate.lt(&0.0)).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.gt(0.0) : {}", sample_rate.gt(&0.0)).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.eq(0.0) : {}", sample_rate.eq(&0.0)).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.lt(0.1) : {}", sample_rate.lt(&0.1)).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.gt(0.1) : {}", sample_rate.gt(&0.1)).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.eq(0.1) : {}", sample_rate.eq(&0.1)).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.lt(-0.1) : {}", sample_rate.lt(&-0.1)).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.gt(-0.1) : {}", sample_rate.gt(&-0.1)).unwrap();
        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "sample_rate.eq(-0.1) : {}", sample_rate.eq(&-0.1)).unwrap();
        

        loop {

        }
    }

}
```

If I run the above code as is, I get the following wrong comparisons.

```
Sample rate: 280.00000
sample_rate.to_bits() : 1133248512
sample_rate.is_sign_negative() : false
sample_rate.is_sign_positive() : true
sample_rate.is_nan() : false
sample_rate.is_finite() : true
sample_rate.is_infinite() : true
sample_rate.is_normal() : false
sample_rate.is_subnormal() : false
sample_rate.lt(0.0) : false
sample_rate.gt(0.0) : false
sample_rate.eq(0.0) : true
sample_rate.lt(0.1) : false
sample_rate.gt(0.1) : false
sample_rate.eq(0.1) : true
sample_rate.lt(-0.1) : false
sample_rate.gt(-0.1) : false
sample_rate.eq(-0.1) : true
```

However, if I un-comment the line above and comment out this portion:

```
        let mut sample_rate = 100.0f32;
        for _ in 1..10 {
            sample_rate = sample_rate + 20.0f32;
        }
```

I get the following results:

```
Sample rate: 280.00000
sample_rate.to_bits() : 1133248512
sample_rate.is_sign_negative() : false
sample_rate.is_sign_positive() : true
sample_rate.is_nan() : false
sample_rate.is_finite() : true
sample_rate.is_infinite() : false
sample_rate.is_normal() : false
sample_rate.is_subnormal() : false
sample_rate.lt(0.0) : false
sample_rate.gt(0.0) : true
sample_rate.eq(0.0) : false
sample_rate.lt(0.1) : false
sample_rate.gt(0.1) : true
sample_rate.eq(0.1) : false
sample_rate.lt(-0.1) : false
sample_rate.gt(-0.1) : true
sample_rate.eq(-0.1) : false
```

I have tried: taking the truncated value of the float, installing avr-gcc-12 instead of my system default of 5.4.0.

My toml looks like the following:

```
[package]
name = "f32demo"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["thefoxrhythm"]
edition = "2021"
license = "MIT OR Apache-2.0"

[[bin]]
name = "f32demo"
test = false
bench = false

[dependencies]
panic-halt = "0.2.0"
ufmt = "0.2.0"
nb = "0.1.2"
embedded-hal = "0.2.3"
ufmt_float ="0.2.0"

[dependencies.avr-device]
version = "0.5.0"
features = ["atmega2560"]

[dependencies.arduino-hal]
git = "https://github.com/rahix/avr-hal"
rev = "4c9c44c314eb061ee20556ef10d45dea36e75ee4"
features = ["arduino-mega2560"]

# Configure the build for minimal size - AVRs have very little program memory
[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"
lto = true
opt-level = "s"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
codegen-units = 1
debug = true
lto = true
strip = true
opt-level = 1
```

And is based off this template: https://github.com/Rahix/avr-hal-template.git

Answer (score 0):

I found in a bug report  [Floating-point casts (sometimes) don't work on AVR #108489](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/108489)  that by adding

```
build-std-features = ["compiler-builtins-mangled-names"]
```

to `./cargo/config.toml` the comparisons start working again.